# Center an element vertically inside an already vertically centered element

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to center my `.get-started-btn` vertically within a bootstrap column. I believe that the problem may be because this button is already placed inside a div with `display: table-cell` so i cannot create a `table-cell` within another `table-cell`? Is there another way to center the button vertically?

See my fiddle:
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yakd65eu/)

```
<div class="page-wrap">
    <main>

      <div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <h1 class="page-header">Flash <span class="page-header-label">Cards</span></h1>
              <p class="lead intro-text">
                Flash Cards is a simple solution for anyone trying to memorize new things or study for that next big test.
                Create your own personal deck of flash cards in minutes and we will track your results to ensure that
                you know your stuff.
              </p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="vcenter">
                <a href="#/getting-started" class="btn btn-lg btn-success get-started-btn">Get Started</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- end row -->

        </div> <!-- end container -->
      </div> <!-- end jumbotron -->

    </main>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.page-wrap {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
main {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#jumbotron {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: none;
}
.vcenter {
  display: table;
  height: 100%; /* does nothing */
  width: 100%; /*pushes element to new line */
  text-align: center;
}
.vcenter a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: none;
}
```

Comment: I need the right column's height to match the size of the left column's height and then i want the button to be centered

Comment: Post a complete code example in your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for misunderstanding your question.  Once I increased the width, I saw the two columns.

You can vertically center the button by adding these styles:

```
.row {
  display: table-cell;
}

.vcenter a {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);}
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5guy9p83/1)

Comment: np, i figured that's what happened. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does div with paragraph will always have the same content? If yes then you could try:

```
.vcenter {
    line-height: 270px; /*height of entire div on the left*/
}
```

And remove this:

```
.vcenter a {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
    }
```

Comment: this is a creative solution. I was mostly interested in finding out how to center it exactly, as I run into this issue somewhat often, but I may end up resorting to some type of hack like this.. thanks